# Do browsers implement the websocket protocol differently?

Tags: c#, websocket

Wrote a simple websocket echo server. After a handshake in chrome, the buffer is empty and the method `await acceptData.ReceiveAsync(bytes);`is waiting for me to send a message from the browser.
But through opera and yandex, after a handshake, an incomprehensible buffer will immediately whine, although I haven’t sent anything yet.

In chrome await acceptData.ReceiveAsync(bytes); debug is waiting for me to send a message from the browser, and bytes is empty there. This is what opera gives out, other bytes in yandex.
[image]
I can’t understand, or I didn’t do something correctly, or the essence of the question.

```
class WS
{
    private readonly string GUID = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
    private readonly string ip;
    private readonly int port;
    byte[] Segment { get; } = new byte[512];
    public Socket socket { get; set; }

    public WS(int port, string ip)
    {
        this.port = port;
        this.ip = ip;
        IPAddress[] ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(this.ip);
        IPEndPoint ipLocalEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress[0], this.port);
        this.socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        this.Bind(ipLocalEndPoint);
        this.Listen();
    }
    private byte[] GetHandshake(string key)
    {
        string acceptSHA1 = key + GUID;
        byte[] encodingBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(acceptSHA1);
        byte[] hash = SHA1.HashData(encodingBytes);
        var hashString = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);

        byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n" +
            "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" +
            "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" +
            "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + hashString +
            "\r\n\r\n");
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msg));
        return msg;
    }

    public async Task<int> GetKeyWS(Socket acceptData)
    {
        await acceptData.ReceiveAsync(this.Segment);

        HttpInfo headersKey = new HttpInfo(this.Segment);

        byte[] buffer = GetHandshake(headersKey.GetHeaderValue("Sec-WebSocket-Key"));
        await acceptData.SendAsync(buffer);

        byte[] bytes = new byte[65536];

        while (true)
        {
            
            if (bytes[0] == 136)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(bytes[i]);
                }

                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                await acceptData.ReceiveAsync(bytes); // Here come not clear bytes
                
                Console.WriteLine(acceptData.RemoteEndPoint);
                int payload = bytes[1] & 127;

                int payloadLength = (bytes[1] & 127) < 126 ? bytes[1] & 127 : BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[] { bytes[3], bytes[2] }, 0);

                byte[] dataBuffer;

                byte[] slice = new byte[4];

                int offset = 0;

                if (payloadLength <= 125)
                {
                    slice = bytes[2..^5];
                    offset = 2;
                }

                int payload_first_byte = offset + 4;
                byte[] decode = new byte[payloadLength];

                for (int i = 0; i < payload; ++i, ++payload_first_byte)
                {
                    decode[i] = (byte)(bytes[payload_first_byte] ^ slice[i % 4]);

                }
                dataBuffer = new byte[] { 129, Convert.ToByte(payload) };
                byte[] arraySend = new byte[dataBuffer.Length + decode.Length];

                Array.Copy(dataBuffer, 0, arraySend, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
                Array.Copy(decode, 0, arraySend, 2, decode.Length);

                await acceptData.SendAsync(arraySend);
            }
        }
    }
    private void Bind(IPEndPoint ep)
    {
        this.socket.Bind(ep);
    }
    private void Listen()
    {
        this.socket.Listen();
    }
}
internal class Program
{
    static async Task<int> Main()
    {
        WS ws = new(7878, "192.168.0.2");

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var acceptAsync = await ws.socket.AcceptAsync();

                new Thread(async () => await ws.GetKeyWS(acceptAsync)).Start();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably check the result from `ReceiveAsync` before trying to use the data, and not just blindly assume it succeeds.

Comment: @JonasH I checked, in chrome it is 0, but in others it is not empty, and then I don’t know what to do